# How to solve "std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&)"

Tags: c++, file, variables

I get an error about `std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&)` when compiling this code:

```
FileEXt = ".conf";
const char* FileEX = FileEXt.c_str();

const char* File = Uname + FileEX;

string File = Uname + FileEXt;

ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(File);
```

Full code:

```
LPCSTR lpPathName = ".\\DB";

SetCurrentDirectoryA(lpPathName);

string Uname, Pword;
cout << "Please enter a name: ";
cin >> Uname;

cout << '\n' << '\n';
cin >> Pword;
            
system("CLS");
cout << "Username: " << Uname << '\n' << "Password: " << Pword << '\n';

const char* FileEXt = ".conf";
const char* Unames = Uname.c_str();
const char* FileEX = FileEXt;

string File = Uname + FileEXt;

ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(File);

if ( outFile.fail() )
{
    outFile << Uname << '\n' << Pword;
    outFile.close();
}
else
{
    cout << Uname << " already exists!" << '\n';
    Sleep(3000);
    return 0;
}
```

This code is supposed to create a file that stores a name in the DB directory.

Comment: `Unames + FileEX` You can't add two `const char*`s.

Comment: You cannot add pointers to pointers. You should use `std::string` to express strings that are concatenated. What do you want to do? Why are you using pointers?

Comment: `FileEXt` is a string, but `Unames` and `FileEX` are `const char*`. If you want to perform concatenation with `+`, you need to keep acting on `std::string`s and only at the end use the C-style string.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/nG75Tn7vP `<source>:10:31: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator+'`

Comment: Without information of what you want to do, the solution may be "delete all of these meaingless statements".

Comment: After the edit: Is that the full text of the error? And is that really the error you get when compiling _this_ code? (For instance, this code has a totally different error where you're declaring two variables of different types both named `File`.)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of code snippets that are not suitable to pass to compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `std::string` to `ofstream::open()`.  Prior to C++11, `open()` did not accept a `std::string` as input, only a `const char*` pointer, eg:

```
outFile.open(File.c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me but I already realized this

Comment: @Shrug Well, you said you were getting an error with `open(std::string&)`, but you didn't say what the error actually was, so I had to guess. This is what happens when you leave out important details.

Comment: The error was in the title and at the start of the question.

Comment: No, the *actual error message verbatim* is not mentioned anywhere in your post, or in comments. `std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&)` is not an error message, it is a method declaration. Not the same thing.